# Chrome keeps asking to save PDF and never opens it

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, adobe-reader

I have a program that generates PDF files in a temp folder and opens it automatically. From my laptop, the pdf loads just fine by Chrome. See pictures below.

The PDFs are forms dynamically filled by the program.

However, when Adobe Acrobat Reader opens it (from a colleague's computer), the form isn't loaded after the second page. I think it may be an issue with the program, but Chrome and Foxit Reader both load it correctly with all the information.

I do not have Adobe Reader on my laptop, thus Chrome is my PDF reader by default. On my colleague's, Adobe Reader is the reader by default. I tried switching the default settings to Chrome, but on open, it keeps asking a location to save it, and again and again (it never opens, it just copies the file everywhere...)

Since it's a company computer, it's impossible for me to uninstall Adobe Reader, any suggestions to fix Chrome?

Chrome page 1 (correct result) : 
[image: Chrome Page 1]

Chrome page 2 (correct result) : 
[image: Chrome page 2]

Adobe Page 1 (Page 1 is okay) : 
[image: Adobe Page 1]

Adobe page 2 (not okay) : 
[image: Adobe Page 2 (wrong)]

I can't post photos of the parameters of the computer now, but will do so if needed.

Comment: Just so I understand. You have PDF files, and you want to them automatically open using CHROME and not Adobe Reader. How is any of the 'Program that generates PDF files' relevant to this question?

Comment: What version of Adobe Acrobat Reader, maybe it's too old to support the forms. Or maybe it's blocking it.

Comment: I tried putting all the details. Let's say this : why Chrome keeps downloading documents instead of opening them? Can't fix Adobe since it seems like a compatibility issue, so I need to get Chrome working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your Chrome Settings.

[PDFs don't open automatically in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213030?hl=en)

Open PDFs in Chrome

1. On your computer, open Chrome
2. At the top right, click More More and then **Settings**.
3. At the bottom, click **Advanced**.
4. Under "Privacy and security," click **Site settings**.
5. Near the bottom, click **PDF documents**.
6. Turn *off* **Download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome**.

Chrome will now open PDFs automatically when you click them.

This is how it should look.

[image]

Comment: It's not that it doesn't open them automatically, it just doesn't open them. I'll try this tomorrow, i'll get back to you.

Comment: Can't do it since it's managed by company...

Comment: Your company controls if you can enter your chrome settings? Okay...

Comment: Yes, very strict... I'm very annoyed by it. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Maybe you should ask another question in an attempt to fix your form, since you can't adjust your chrome settings. Sorry brother